# How to pass props to a router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a file route.js which has

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import {HashRouter ,Route,Link} from 'react-router-dom'

const Router = (props) => (
  <HashRouter>
    <div>
      <Route exact path="/" render={() => <list data={props.data}/>}/>
      <Route path="/list" render={() => <Table data={props.data}/>}/>
    </div>
  </HashRouter>
```

here is the edit page code-

```
import React, { Component} from 'react'

export default class Edit extends Component {
  render() {

    return (
      <div>
    <center>{this.props.data}</center>
      </div>
    );
  }
  }
```

i want to pass the list data to the next page.how can i pass props to page from router

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass any props to some route you can just pass it through the `params` prop of `Link`.

Here in your case you could just set a button anywhere on the FreindList page which should be like:

```
<Link to='edit' params={{data: props.data.name}}>
  <button>Edit</button>
</Link>
```

Further you can access this array in the edit page aswel.

don not forget to import Link from react router

Since you are using `react-router-dom` which is react router 4, you can just use, something like this:

```
<Link to={{
  pathname: '/edit',
  state: { data: props.data.name }
}}>
  <button>Edit</button>
</Link>
```

You will get it in `this.props.location.state` in the edit component.

For more documentation on react router 4 check [this](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/) out

Comment: can you tel me how can i access this prop in edit page.

Comment: log out this.props on `componentDidMount` on edit page, you'll see the data object in one of the router properties.

Comment: i guess i am going wrong somewhere...i am not able to access the data in edit page...could you please help me?

Comment: right now i just want the clicked row data to b displayed on the edit page.

Comment: this is what i added in the list.js <Link to={"./edit/"} params={{name: props.data.name}}>Edit</Link>

Comment: can you tel me how can i access the name in edit page?

Comment: this is what i wrote in edit page export default class Edit extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
    <center> {this.props.name} </center>
      </div>
    );
  }
  }

Comment: no I have provided the code up there for the link just use that

Comment: I could probably help you if I could see the code, or atleast put the edit page code on a gist and share it with me, this is not helping

Comment: why aren't you using the code I provided for the edit button, your code is wrong right ther

Comment: after i added that code i am getting errors. so i made these modifications

Comment: sure but just set the to property of Link to `edit` instead of `{"./edit/"} ` and put this function on before your render function, 

`componentDidMount () {
  console.log(this.props)
}`

and tell me what do you get in the console

Comment: this is what i got- Object {match: Object, location: Object, history: Object, staticContext: undefined}
history
:
Object
location
:
Object
match
:
Object
staticContext
:
undefined
__proto__
:
Object

Comment: can you tell me which version of react-router are you using?

Comment: "react-dom": "^15.5.4",
    "react-router": "^4.1.1",

Comment: I did not notice that you were using react router 4, check out I just edited the answer, finally you can get this data on the edit page on `this.props.location.state` object.

Comment: Thanks alot @aditya